# how to show dynamic wordpress skin switching

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to show dynamic wordpress skin switching based on used input.

For example.

mywpsite.com/theme/red - shows red skin 
 mywpsite.com/theme/green - shows green skin 
 mywpsite.com/theme/blue - shows blue skin

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This could be done pretty easily with Kohana (http://www.kohanaphp.com/), which is my suggestion.  Other wise you will need to write a controller of your own that deliminates the URI and includes the correct view.

Comment: Thanks david, but i need it in wp only since its my task. Let me find a way